# Add and edit nodes using the main theme

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, I could use [hook_admin_paths](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7.x) to decide if a page used the main or admin theme. [This has changed in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224207). This option is now set in a route definition. Existing routes, like *node.add*, [can be altered](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones). However, looking in *node.routing.yml*, under *node.add*, I do not see `_admin_route: TRUE`, which I intended to alter to `FALSE`.

What do I need to alter, and how, so that adding and editing nodes is done using the main theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this in UI, see the checkbox at the end of the theme list in */admin/appearance*:

> [x] Use the administration theme when editing or creating content

This config option is then used to alter the route in the following code example, which would also answer how to alter the route in a route subscriber:

**NodeAdminRouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()**

```
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($this->configFactory->get('node.settings')->get('use_admin_theme')) {
      foreach ($collection->all() as $route) {
        if ($route->hasOption('_node_operation_route')) {
          $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

More info https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative could be to use the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module: there is an available Reaction called 'theme' that allows to set the theme depending on any available Condition (system path, content type, etc...)