# Add content screens from the front end

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I am building a web application (for trusted users), so the logged in user will have the ability to add content. However currently, when the user wants to add a record, they move from the frontend theme to the Admin UI, (the "Content > Add Content > Article" page).

This looks unprofessional, and I don't really want non-technical users let loose on the Admin UI.

How can I create "frontend" pages to let the user Add New Nodes or Edit Nodes?

(Essentially, I want to mimic the Add Article and Edit Article screens, but on the frontend of the site).

I'm not afraid of a bit of custom coding if necessary, but need to be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244663/add-and-edit-nodes-using-the-main-theme

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/appearance, uncheck the box name 'Use the administration theme when editing or creating content', and save.